# Forbid caching of image built with base64 string

Tags: javascript, html, browser, cross-browser

Is there a simple way to forbid browser caching of image, generated from a base64 string?

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,......">
```

I'm searching for a simple, but granular solution that would allow me to forbid caching per image, like this (in case we are loading image from some URI)

```
 <img src="someUri?someRandomKey=someRandomValue">
```